# Adding the values from a column in mysql to a list or a tuple

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to select the values from a mysql table based on certain condition and add them to a list or a tuple.

```
from connect_to_db import db_conn, cursor

 mapped_list=[]
 sql_mapped="""SELECT internal_id FROM table 
 WHERE name='XXX' AND DATE(datetime_recieved) =DATE(NOW()) AND internal_id!=0"""
```

I want to save the result in the list but not sure how to do it.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the desired outcome.

```
def get_mapped():
 mapped_list=[]
 sql_mapped="""SELECT internal_id FROM table 
 WHERE name='XXX' AND DATE(datetime_recieved) =DATE(NOW()) AND 
 internal_id!=0"""
 cursor.execute(sql_mapped)
 cursor.fetchone()
 rows = cursor.fetchall()
    
    for row in rows:
        mapped_list.append(row)

    print (mapped_list)
    return mapped_list
get_mapped()
```